# Material UI v5, Select component, border: none, doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm using NextJs with material ui v5, and want to set `{border: none}` for Select component from mui, but it doesn't work. I'm applying sx prop object, because I think this is best solution for SSR. I found in [docs](https://mui.com/system/borders/), that I need to set `sx={{ border: 0 }}` for Select component props, but it also doesn't work. Moreover, if I set in sx object `border: 1px solid darkgrey` or `borderRadius: 50px` both work fine.

Here is example from docs with my minor changes:

```
export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  const commonStyles = {
    border: 0,
    // border: '1px solid darkgrey', // it works
    // borderRadius: '50px', //it works
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
          sx={{ ...commonStyles }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Please help, how to turn off border of Select component with sx prop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use variant property from [Select API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/)

```
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
          variant="standard"
        >
```

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-shape-t7u4zq?file=/src/App.js:611-619)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this method doesn't work for me, because Select component has underline with ```variant="standard"```. I found that I can to use Menu component and stylize it easily how I need with sx object

Comment: Good solution too